# Gnuplot, bars in histogram are overlapped, can not be separated, why

Tags: gnuplot, histogram, overlap

I tried to plot a data sheet like this by Gnuplot.

```
Area_height MIC PCC_SQRT    
Power   0.734852672 0.618902589 1
"Powder size (D90)" 0.712130033 0.702902099 2
"Powder size (D50)" 0.712130033 0.384749485 2
"Powder size (D10)" 0.712130033 0.448956759 2
Speed   0.590181886 0.582894451 1
"Energy density"    0.519402585 0.598153661 1
Cr  0.44654505  0.584812588 4
Liquidus    0.44654505  0.584812588 3
Ni  0.44654505  0.584812588 4
Mn  0.44654505  0.584812588 4
Mo  0.44654505  0.584812588 4
```

Column 4 is used to define colors for the bar.

I plotted with the following commands:

```
set style data histograms

plot "new/Area_height_MIC_PCC_New.txt" using 0:2:4:xtic(1) \
with boxes lc variable fill pattern 1, "" using 0:3:4:xtic(1) \
with boxes lc variable fill solid 1
```

or

```
set style histogram clustered

plot "new/Area_height_MIC_PCC_New.txt" using 0:2:4:xtic(1) \
with boxes lc variable fill pattern 1, "" using 0:3:4:xtic(1) \
with boxes lc variable fill solid 1
```

but the figure I got is like this,

[image: output]

the bars in solid and in pattern are overlapped. This is not what I want. I want them displayed next to each other.

Can someone tell me what is the problem?

Comment: You must also use the `histogram` style when plotting, instead of `boxes`: `set style histogram cluster gap 1; plot ... with histogram`

Comment: @Christoph Thanks a lot. I tried: plot "new/Area_height_MIC_PCC_New.txt" using 2:4:xtic(1) with histogram lc variable fill pattern 1, "" using 3:4:xtic(1) with histogram lc variable fill solid 1, but came error message: Too many columns in using specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you almost had it. You have to shift the boxes in x-direction by some value. This you can do e.g. by `($0-0.2)` and `($0+0.2)`.

**Code:**

```
### box plot with color from column
reset session

$Data <<EOD
# Area_height MIC PCC_SQRT
Power   0.734852672 0.618902589 1
"Powder size (D90)" 0.712130033 0.702902099 2
"Powder size (D50)" 0.712130033 0.384749485 2
"Powder size (D10)" 0.712130033 0.448956759 2
Speed   0.590181886 0.582894451 1
"Energy density"    0.519402585 0.598153661 1
Cr  0.44654505  0.584812588 4
Liquidus    0.44654505  0.584812588 3
Ni  0.44654505  0.584812588 4
Mn  0.44654505  0.584812588 4
Mo  0.44654505  0.584812588 4
EOD

set xrange[-0.5:]
set yrange[0:]
set boxwidth 0.3
set xtics rotate by 45 right offset first 0.2
plot $Data u ($0-0.2):2:4:xtic(1) w boxes lc var fill pattern 1, \
     '' u  ($0+0.2):3:4 w boxes lc var fill solid 1.0
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]